# Login control and redirecting to appropriate pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, authentication

Im developing an asp.net application and trying to get authorization to work. When I first start my website I want to see login page and then depending what's the name of the user, I want to bring them to appropriate page eg when login succeed as doctor -- redirect to Doctor.aspx, when login authorization succeeded as secretary -- go to secretary page. I tried doing it with web administration using "Manage access rules" but once login passes it just redirects me default.aspx (which doesn't exist). How do I redirect it depending on who's the user ? This is the structure of my directory [image]

Comment: You can do it by using .net built in membership [see full tutorial here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076025/login-control-and-redirecting-to-appropriate-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can create like this

```
string redirecturl;

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserRole"].ToString()=="Secretary")
    redirecturl="Secretery/index.aspx";
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserRole"].ToString()=="Doctor")
    redirecturl="Doctor/index.aspx";
```

That's one way. Also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2006/07/01/part-1-of-3-creating-sub-projects-in-iis-with-web-application-projects.aspx) article might be helpful for you.